# About indirect object

Tags: grammar

Can verb "set" have an indirect object? E.g "I set myself a task to do that" Where "myself" Is the indirect object. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, "myself" is Oi and "a task to do that" is Od. Btw, the infinitival clause "to do that" is complement of the noun "task"

Comment: ***Set me free**!* and ***Set me to work*** are syntactically *slightly* different to ***Set me a task***, but they all feature ***me*** as an "object / patient".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wouldn't "a task" be the patient in the third sentence, since that is what is being set? If not, then what role would "a task" have?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: I'd say *Set me a task* is an imperative, so the unspecified "agent" is ***you***, and the "patient" is ***me***. The ***task*** looks like an indirect object, but I don't know if that has its own name in the agent/patient lexicon

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Goal" is sometimes used for the beneficiary of the action. Both the word-order of the two objects and the fact that "me" can be replaced by "for me" suggest that "me" is an IO / goal. I think that "task" is the DO, because we can rewrite the sentence as "set a task for me".

Comment: I'm not much interested in in the terminology itself here. I certainly don't need to know such things to help *me* learn English, and it's not obvious to me that *non-Anglophone learners* gain any benefit on that front. I'd say it's only important for those learners who need to pass exams, and given there are different authorities working with different terminologies, those learners should stick to whatever their *teacher* tells them. Getting things mixed up between competing terminological frameworks is a recipe for total chaos!

Comment: I was just making the point that *Set me free!* and *Set me to work* and *Set me a task* really are syntactically different. Call them what you like.

Answer (score 2):

"Set" is one of the words with the most senses in English.  The OED entry for "set" is about 50000 words long, longer than many novels, even Wiktionary lists about 100 different senses.

"Set" can be used with an indirect object and a direct object as in the example, when it is being used in the sense of "give myself a task".  The direct object is usually "task" or "goal" or a word with a similar meaning.